# converting a website from asp.net to asp.net mvc and formatting seems off

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am converting over a website and using the same .css files.

its really strange as the site looks slightly different in terms of formatting (font sizes, padding, spacing, etc . )

does this make any sense because i am using the same stylesheets.

is there anything that asp.net webforms was doing that was magic.  i am reviewing the actual html which is identical.

Comment: in the asp.net mvc i see this: 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

for the regular asp.net, i dont see any doc type

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/  Basically, DocTypes tell the browser how to handle the html.  Try removing the DocType from the MVC aspx and see if it renders the same as the non MVC aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that in your old site, the ordering of the CSS files in the HTML are different?

Let's say that, in your main CSS file (main.css), you set a font size of anything inside the body tag to be 10px, and in a page-specific CS file (thisPage.css), you set the font size of anything in the body tag to be 12px.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="thisPage.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

In a page rendering, the font size will be 12px. The page-specific CSS will override anything that matches a rule in the main CSS (unless of course, you apply the [!important](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) rule!).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="thisPage.css"/>
    <link  rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

In this page rendering, the font size will be 10px.

This may be something to consider as, because these are cascading rules, the order is important.